# Function with partial derivatives being Lipschitz satisfy $f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) - f(x) \leq r^2 $

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that all of its partial derivatives are Lipschitz with constant $\leq 1$ (or even better, $||f||_{C^{1,1}(\Omega)} \leq 1 $) where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, we may assume that it is connected and bounded if necessary.

If $0 < r < 1/4$, and $x_0 \in \Omega$ so that
$B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega$ then we have that for all
$x \in B_r(x_0)$ holds
$$f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) - f(x) \leq r^2 $$

What i've done is this, add $0$ in the form of $\nabla f(x) \cdot (x-x_0) - \nabla f(x)\cdot (x-x_0)$ to obtain
$$f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) - f(x)   = f(x_0) + \nabla [f(x_0) - f(x)] \cdot (x-x_0) - f(x)  + \nabla f(x)\cdot (x-x_0) \leq f(x_0) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)\cdot (x-x_0) + r^2   $$ but I dont know how to control the term $f(x_0) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)\cdot (x-x_0) $

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem to write $ f(x)-f(x_0)=\nabla f(c)\cdot (x-x_0)$ where $c$ is a point on the segment of endpoints $x$ and $x_0$.